# Swagger Node: Use custom config and folder structure

Tags: node.js, swagger

I am looking into Swagger for Node.js. I like the idea of it, but I am not a fan of some of the auto generated files and the structure. I thought it was possible to change this, but I am having a hard time finding out how. For example, swagger places all controller files in api/controllers. Can I alter this to just be routes for example? Is there a way to easily configure what files/directories to include or exclude?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link for swagger for node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express, it provides much detail for this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35521043)